# Breakpoints not working in dart editor

Tags: dart, dartium

I cannot get breakpoints working in the Dart editor.  I'm using a launch configuration to point to a URL for a local MVC3 site.  Debugging is enabled.  Oddly enough, dart editor will break on exceptions and come into focus, but completely ignores breakpoints.  I've tried 32-bit dart editor with 32-bit jre, and 64-bit dart editor with 64-bit jre to no avail.

Comment: I think that the launch configuration needs to use a Dart Editor supplied url:port rather than a custom URL in order to use debugging.  My understanding is that this is how the two parts communicate (but I may be wrong).

Comment: What I found interesting is that there is communication between dartium and the dart editor because it will break on exceptions, just not on breakpoints.

Comment: Could you post a minimum working example? I'll paste it into mine to see if I can reproduce the problem. I'm also using the newest version.

Comment: It's hard to post an example because you have to reproduce the environment, which is an MVC 3 site being hosted by the Visual Studio http server, although I suspect this issue is present regardless of what http server is used.  My run configuration is using Dart VM, URL `http://localhost:62939`, run in checked mode, enable debugging.

Like I said, dart editor breaks on exceptions, so dartium and dart editor *are* communicating.  I think the best first step is to replicate my run configuration using a URL pointing to a locally hosted dart app and seeing if this issue is easily reproduced.

Comment: I have a similar setup and was experiencing the the same symptoms (DartEditor ignoring breakpoints but showing source on exceptions) until I discovered that the html script tag was using an old src path, so the more recent dart app was never being downloaded. This is an odd behavior; the old (non-existing) dart app was executed even though the server returned 404. There may possibly be some misguided caching going on in Chromium and/or DartEditor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're running into this issue:

http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=3748

Basically, we're trying to set breakpoints based off the URLs of our internal localhost:3030 server, but the browser can't resolve those as the content is being loaded from a different url.

Comment: That must be it.  Thanks a lot!